# Rotate text in FPDF+FPDI

Tags: text, rotation, fpdf, fpdi

I've got a problem regarding the text rotation in FPDF+FPDI...
I've found a class, but it doesn't work.

I need to rotate the first text 180°.

My working code so far:

```
$pdf = new FPDI('P','mm',array(225.37,261.719));
$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,0);
$pdf->AddFont('Chrioc','','CHRIOC__.php');
$mid_x=112.685;

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("source/empty.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx,0,0,225.37,261.719);
$pdf->SetFont('Chrioc','',55);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Text($mid_x-($pdf->GetStringWidth("aaa")/2),100,"aaa");
$pdf->Text($mid_x-($pdf->GetStringWidth("bbb")/2),168,"bbb");

$pdf->Output(); ?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to rotate text in my pdf using the class used in this [url page](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script2.php)

Basically, I had created a class with their functions with FPDI as a parent, and imported in my code, instead of

```
// Your code    
$pdf = new FPDI('P','mm',array(225.37,261.719));
// Import changed
$pdf = new PDF_Rotate('P','mm',array(225.37,261.719));
```

Then I could just use

```
$pdf->SetXY(2, -5);
$pdf->RotatedText(5,250,"Example of rotated text",90);
```

Here the full code:
PDF_Rotate.php (Importing from FPDI instead of FPDF as the sample)

```
class PDF_Rotate extends \FPDI
{
    var $angle=0;

    function Rotate($angle,$x=-1,$y=-1)
    {
        if($x==-1)
            $x=$this->x;
        if($y==-1)
            $y=$this->y;
        if($this->angle!=0)
            $this->_out('Q');
        $this->angle=$angle;
        if($angle!=0)
        {
            $angle*=M_PI/180;
            $c=cos($angle);
            $s=sin($angle);
            $cx=$x*$this->k;
            $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k;
            $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5F %.5F %.5F %.5F %.2F %.2F cm 1 0 0 1 %.2F %.2F cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
        }
    }

    function _endpage()
    {
        if($this->angle!=0)
        {
            $this->angle=0;
            $this->_out('Q');
        }
        parent::_endpage();
    }

    function RotatedText($x,$y,$txt,$angle)
    {
        //Text rotated around its origin
        $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
        $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
        $this->Rotate(0);
    }

    function RotatedImage($file,$x,$y,$w,$h,$angle)
    {
        //Image rotated around its upper-left corner
        $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
        $this->Image($file,$x,$y,$w,$h);
        $this->Rotate(0);
    }
}
```

Here in the other file, importing the class.

```
$pdf = new  PDF_Rotate();
$pdf->SetXY(2, -5);
$pdf->RotatedText(5,250,"Example of rotated text",90);
```